# PayPal Payments Pro Direct Payment API

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I am planning on setting up a Paypal Payments Pro account and posting to their Direct Payment API with credit card billing information via our website. In an effort not to worry about PCI compliance, I would rather not have the credit card information pass through our web server and post directly to PayPal from client code. What is the most simple way to do this? Perhaps use a PayPal hosted form and imbed it withing our webiste via an iframe? Can someone please list out a few recommended solutions and where to start looking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment) won't do that.  What you want, per your explanation, is [PayPal Payments Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced) (or sometimes they do call it Payments Pro Hosted, which just confuses people and is annoying.)

I personally prefer the full Pro, DDP over Advanced/Hosted.  For PCI compliance, all you need to do is make sure you're using a valid SSL certificate on your server, and also make sure you're not saving any credit card details to your database.

Comment: I'd rather use Payments Pro, but I do not want to be bothered with any PCI Compliance(i.e. I don't want to host the billing form, but would like to be able to theme it with CSS). I heard there are PCI Compliant hosted solutions which allow you to basically put your "credit card info" form on their site and you simply re-direct to their site from yours. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What you're explaining is what [PayPal Payments Advanced](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced) gives you.

Comment: I read that advanced does not offer the "customizable" part of my need. Can I theme the billing form hosted on paypal to have a similar look/feel as my site? Also, I would need the transaction ID or payment ID at some point, could the hosted billing form post the ID to my merchant site after a success?

Comment: It's pretty limited.  If you want full control you'll need to go with the full Pro package.